# Multiple form for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

I have two models named Station and Stream. Station has_many streams. I have a form for streams at Streams/new page and on submission sets the station_id to current_user.station_id (I do have another model User has_many stations). I need to allow user to click a button "add more streams" on the form, which would duplicate the existing Streams form and show only one submit button. So that when user submits the form, it creates multiple entries in the streams table all with station_id set at current_user.station_id. Also user will never create a station. Its created by the Admin and allocated to particular users. How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you find something to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method in your model. You can find a great example of how to do this here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=similar

You can also do this really simply by using the cocoon gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: The thing is I want to operate on same model instead of multiple ones. Same model, multiple records in the database is the requirement

Comment: Something like duplicate forms which can be submitted at once to store multiple records in the table